# Manage attributes inheritance with RESTeasy

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs, pojo

I'm using RESTeasy to convert a json from the payload to a POJO in the web server. I encounter a problem when one of those POJO member is generic.

For example:

```
public class MainPOJO
{
    private MyParentClass c;

    [...]
}

public class MyParentClass
{
    [...]
}

public class MyFirstChildClass extends MyParentClass
{
    private int number;

    [...]
}

public class MySecondChildClass extends MyParentClass
{
    private boolean isTrue;

    [...]
}
```

In the request payload (PUT) made by the client, you can found something like this json (notice that I send a MyFirstChildClass equivalent in json format in the "c" attribute):

```
{
    c: {number:10}
}
```

Is there any way to tell RESTeasy that the property "c" in the MainPOJO can be either an instance of MyParentClass, MyFirstChildClass or MySecondChildClass?

Currently, it just try to instanciate a MyParentClass new instance but throw an error saying that property, for exemple, "number" is not mark as ignorable. But I wish it could be more intelligent and instantiate an object from the right class in the tree according to the properties in the json.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the Jettison or Jackson provider?

Comment: We are using Jackson provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Jackson provider, then the best way to handle this would be via the `JsonTypeInfo` annotation. Using it informs Jackson that you want type hints included in generated JSON, that it can use to resolve the actual type when it comes to de-serialization.

To ***always*** include type information when your `MyParentClass` is being serialized, you would annotate the class itself:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.CLASS, include=As.PROPERTY, property="class")
public class MyParentClass {
}
```

Alternatively, to only include the type information for `MyParentClass` when a `MainPojo` object is being serialized, you would annotate the field:

```
public class MainPOJO {
    @JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.CLASS, include=As.PROPERTY, property="class")
    private MyParentClass c;
}
```

Refer to the [Jackson documentation on JsonTypeInfo](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonTypeInfo.html) for more detail on overrides and options.